# Oracle Select statement execution

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

what happens when we execute a select query to retrieve a million row (just an example) but the sga is sized less , suppose 250mb ? how would the oracle select query execute, what would be the output?

Answer (score 1):

For optimal performance in most systems, the entire SGA should fit in real memory. **

> If it does not, and if virtual memory is used to store parts of it,
>   then overall database system performance can decrease dramatically.

** The reason for this is that portions of the SGA are paged (written to and read from disk) by the operating system. The amount of memory dedicated to all shared areas in the SGA also has performance impact.